# r identify two populations in scatterplot

Tags: r, subset, scatter-plot, raster

I am comparing two rasters with a simple scatter plot of cell-by-cell plot, and find that I have two seemingly different populations:

[image: true scatterplot]

Now I am trying to extract the locations of each of these populations (by isolating the row IDs, e.g.) so I can see where they fall in the rasters and maybe understand why I get this behavior.    Here is a reproducible example:
`X <- seq(1,1000,1)`
`Z <- runif(1000, 1, 2)`
`A = c(1.2 * X * Z + 100)`
`B = c(0.6 * X * Z )`
`df = data.frame(X = c(X,X), Y = c(A,B))`
`plot(df$X,df$Y)`
[image: sample scatter]
Also, my original data has some 1,000,000 rows, so the solution needs to support a large data frame as well.
Any ideas on how I can isolate each of these groups?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What's the desired result? In your original pic, it looks like you have a lot of overlap. How would you resolve that? Are you just trying to separate them by eye? Or do you have a mathematical definition of "isolated groups"?

Answer (score 5):

Spectral Clustering is useful in identifying clusters of points that has a clear boundary. A great advantage is that it is unsupervised, i.e. not relying much on human judgement, although the method is slow and some hyperparameters (e.g. number of clusters) need to be supplied.

Below is the code for clustering. The code takes about a few minutes in your case.

```
library(kernlab)
specc_df <- specc(as.matrix(df),centers = 2)
plot(df, col = specc_df)
```

The result is an obvious plot of two clusters of points.
[image: obviously two groups of points]

Comment: Thanks raymkchow, but my original data has ~1,000,000 rows, so this solution doesn't seem feasible in this case

Comment: Oh, then we still need some better answers. Can you please add this requirement to the question?

Answer (score 3):

You data has a linear separating line.  You can find it with:

```
plot(df$X,df$Y)
Pts = locator(2)
```

You will want to click on one point between the two groups down by the origin and another on the far right (between the groups).  With your data I got

```
Pts
$x
[1]   0.8066296 994.9723687
$y
[1]   48.56932 1255.32870

## Slope
(Pts$y[2] - Pts$y[1]) / (Pts$x[2] - Pts$x[1])
[1] 1.213841

## Draw the line to confirm 
abline(48,1.2, col="red")

## use the line to distinguish the groups
Group = rep(1, nrow(df))
Group[df$X*1.2 + 48 < df$Y] = 2
plot(df, pch=20, col=Group)
```

[image: Plot]